# Replace $$ or more with single spaceusing Regex in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, analysis, regexp-replace

In the following list of string i want to remove $$ or more with only one space.

eg- if i have $$ then one space character or if there are $$$$ or more then also only 1 space is to be replaced.

I am using the following regex but i'm not sure if it serves the purpose

```
regex_pattern = r"['$$']{2,}?"
```

Following is the test string list:

['1', 'Patna City $$$$ $$$$$$$$View Details', 'Serial No:$$$$5$$$$ $$$$Deed No:$$$$5$$$$ $$$$Token No:$$$$7$$$$ $$$$Reg Year:2020', 'Anil Kumar Singh Alias Anil Kumar$$$$$$$$Executant$$$$$$$$Late. Harinandan Singh$$$$$$$$$$$$Md. Shahzad Ahmad$$$$$$$$Claimant$$$$$$$$Late. Md. Serajuddin', 'Anil Kumar Singh Alias Anil Kumar', 'Executant', 'Late. Harinandan Singh', 'Md. Shahzad Ahmad', 'Claimant', 'Late. Md. Serajuddin', 'Circle:Patna City Mauja: $$$$ $$$$Khata : na$$$$ $$$$Plot :2497 Area(in Decimal):1.5002 Land Type :Res. Branch Road Land Value :1520000 MVR Value :1000000', 'Circle:Patna City Mauja: $$$$ $$$$Khata : na$$$$ $$$$Plot :2497 Area(in Decimal):1.5002 Land Type :Res. Branch Road Land Value :1520000 MVR Value :1000000']

Comment: Your 'test string' looks more like a list of strings and your `regex_pattern` isn't valid Python, Please provide an example of what you actually tried, allowing others to try it for themselves and providing you with an answer.

Comment: @Grismari have edited the post. i have tried it on regex101.com

Comment: this would not solve the problem, we don't want to match the space, we want to replace the $ occurrences (may it be any no) be replaced by single space character @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About

> I am using the following regex but i'm not sure if it serves the
> purpose

The pattern `['$$']{2,}?` can be written as `['$]{2,}?` and matches 2 or more chars being either `'` or `$` in a non greedy way.

Your pattern currently get the right matches, as there are no parts present like `''` or `$'`

As the pattern is non greedy, it will only match 2 chars and will not match all 3 characters in `$$$`

You could write the pattern matching 2 or more dollar signs without making it non greedy so the odd number of `$` will also be matched:

```
regex_pattern = r"\${2,}"
```

In the replacement use a space.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?:

```
import re
for d in data:
    d = re.sub(r'\${2,}', ' ', d)
```